# For all records, Query to sum two records from the same table

Tags: sql, ms-access

Currently I am constructing my own database for my fantasy sports hobby. A query I would like to do would be to find the all the combinations of each record with another record. For example, the columns are name, salary, and a point total. I want a query to display both names together in a column and their combined point total. I have one condition, I would like the sum of their two salaries to be below 12000.

Comment: Can you add sample data and desired result? It would be more easier to understand your question..

Comment: Player1Name, 6000, 30 player2Name, 3000,25. player3Name, 8000,45

Comment: I don’t wanna add any 2 records whose column2 sum > 12000. For example I don’t wanna sum player 1&3 because their sum would be 14000 and I don’t wanna see data if it doesn’t satisfy that condition.

Answer (score 1):

We can try cross joining your tables, with a restriction to make sure we don't get duplicate pairs:

```
SELECT
    t1.name player1, 
    t2.name player2,
    t1.points + t2.points AS point_total
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.salary * 0 = t2.salary * 0
WHERE
    t1.name < t2.name AND
    t1.salary + t2.salary < 12000;
```

The explanation for the `ON` clause is that Access does not support a formal cross join operation.  But, we can simulate it by doing an inner join with a condition that would be true for every combination of records from both tables.

Answer (score 0):

MS Access expresses the `cross join` in the old fashioned way using a comma.  This is just one of many non-standard constructs in MS Access.

So you can do:

```
SELECT t1.name as name1, t2.name as name2,
       (t1.points + t2.points) AS point_total
FROM t as t1,
     t as t2
WHERE t1.name < t2.name AND
      (t1.salary + t2.salary) < 12000;
```